# Make Left and Bottom FacetGrid Spines Visible

Tags: python, seaborn, subplot, facet-grid, catplot

I try to come up with a helper function to plot figure with subplots in Seaborn.

The codes currently look like below:

```
def granular_barplot(data, col_name, separator):
    '''
    data = dataframe
    col_name: the column to be analysed
    separator: column to be plotted in subplot
    '''
    g = sns.catplot(data=data, y=col_name, col=separator, kind='count',color=blue)
    g.fig.set_size_inches(16,8)
    g.fig.suptitle(f'{col_name.capitalize()} Changes by {separator.capitalize()}',fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
    g.despine()
    
    for ax in g.axes.ravel():
        for c in ax.containers:
            ax.bar_label(c)
```

and it produces the graph like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to make the left and bottom spines visible for each subplots in the helper function like below (which is similar to the sns.despine function):
[image]

Comment: Instead of despining the entire thing, why not despine the top and right? [similar to this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082111/how-to-despine-a-matplotlib-and-seaborn-axes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting this style:

```
def granular_barplot(data, col_name, separator):
    '''
    data = dataframe
    col_name: the column to be analysed
    separator: column to be plotted in subplot
    '''
    sns.set_style({'axes.linewidth': 2, 'axes.edgecolor':'black'})
    g = sns.catplot(data=data, y=col_name, col=separator, kind='count',color='blue')
    g.fig.set_size_inches(16,8)
    g.fig.suptitle(f'{col_name.capitalize()} Changes by {separator.capitalize()}',fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
    g.despine()
    
    for ax in g.axes.ravel():
        ax.spines['left'].set_visible(True)
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)

df = sns.load_dataset('tips')
granular_barplot(df, 'sex', 'smoker')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should either be able to pass some settings to seaborn's despine function or use matplotlib's ability to set spine visibility:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1,100)
y = np.arange(1,100)

g = sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y)
plt.title("Seaborn despine")
sns.despine(left=False, bottom=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Seaborn]

```py
g = sns.lineplot(x=x,y=y)
plt.title("False Spines")
g.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
g.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib]